# .htaccess subdomain feeds redirect xml to php not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect subdomain feeds to php files but its not working.

```
feeds.example.com/all/index.xml to feeds/all/index.php
```

redirecting from main domain working.

```
www.example.com/all/index.xml to feeds/all/index.php
```

also subdomain redirects working.

```
feeds.example.com to feeds/index.php
```

I am trying this way.

```
RewriteRule ^feeds/(.*)\.xml$ /feeds/$1.php [L]
```

also tried this way but not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://feeds.example.com/$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://feeds.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)\.xml$ /feeds/$1.php [L]
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://feeds\.example\.com      [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.xml$ /feeds/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Its showing 404 error when trying to access `feeds.example.com/all/index.xml`

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond` and retest.

Comment: I put this in subdomain directory htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ /$1.php [L]` and its working. is there any way to mak it work from root .htaccess

Comment: If sub-domain's `DocumentRoot` is a sub-directory of main domain's then it cannot work from main domain's .htaccess

Comment: yes sub-domain's DocumentRoot is a sub-directory of main domain

Comment: ok in that case this same rule has to be placed in sub-domain's DocumentROot (sub-directory of main domain) also.